# How checkboxes are handled in VBA Excel 2011 for Mac

Tags: excel, macos, vba, checkbox

I have searched thoroughly through the Internet and the Stackoverflow site without success. I've been stuck in a problem for a week and I cannot make heads or tails of it.

I have been studying VBA and my reference book is giving the following example:

```
Private Sub CommandButtons()
Dim intcounter As Integer, xObj As OLEObject
Dim strObj As String
intcounter = 0
strObj = ""

For Each xObj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
If TypeName(xObj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
If xObj.Object.Value = True Then
intcounter = intcounter + 1
strObj = strObj & xObj.Object.Caption & Chr(10)
End If
End If

Next xObj

If intcounter = 0 Then
MsgBox "There were no CheckBoxes selected", , "No Sport"
Else
MsgBox _
"you selected" & intcounter & "checkboxes:" _
& vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
strObj, , "Here is what you checked"
End If

End Sub
```

Unfortunately this code does not work. It is supposed to evaluate every embedded boject on the worksheet. When the code comes across an ActiveX CheckBox, it should determine whether the CheckBox is checked. At the end of the procedure, a MsgBox will appear, confirming how many (if any) CheckBox were checked and their caption.

Can anybody help me with this? Even a link would be more than welcome.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Hi, what issue are you experiencing with the code? Could you update your question to include any errors / what line they're occurring on?

Comment: Hi Gareth, thank you for your interest. There are no error messages. Simply the code doesn't not work as intended. It returns a the MsgBox where no checkboxes are not marked but they are marked actually...

Comment: ActiveX controls can not be used on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend the if condition to:

```
= "CheckBox"
```

You have a space in between which is why.

Just to expand (posted that by mobile):

The `TypeName` function returns the name of the object and when used in an if condition, needs to be referred to in a case sensitive and correct manor. In your case you need to use:

```
If TypeName(xObj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
```

Comment: I tried your correction but it is still giving the wrong MsgBox... this is driving me crazy... I checked the checkboxes properties and they are checkboxes..